# MUI Masonry with Collapse in an Item Overflows the Parent Width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, masonry

Let's say we use [MUI `Masonry`](https://mui.com/components/masonry/) and in each of the items there is a [`Collapse` element](https://mui.com/api/collapse/#main-content) that is expanded if it gets clicked. If you click an item that needs to be moved to another column, it moves the items outside the parent's specified width!

[This CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsivecolumns-material-demo-forked-5xlj0?file=/demo.js) demonstrates the issue. The original view is like:
[image: The original view]

Now, after clicking the first item, which does not require moving, I see:
[image: The second view]

Which is what I expected, but if I click one of the items at the bottom that requires moving it, it creates a new column outside the parent's width.
[image: The view with an extra column that goes beyond the parent width]

Comment: May we look at your implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to share the link https://codesandbox.io/s/responsivecolumns-material-demo-forked-5xlj0?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1):

At the moment dynamic height like that is not supported. See [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/30439).

Comment: Also from a UX perspective, boxes resizing and suddenly jumping columns is an [unexpected layout shift](https://web.dev/cls/#expected-vs.-unexpected-layout-shifts) and should probably be avoided by not using a masonry.